# css and images not recognized by nginx: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: php, nginx, webserver, mime-types

I'm trying to run Rainloop in a subdirectory. http://babylon/webmail. I get the css and js are not recognized. For example:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://babylon/webmail/rainloop/v/1.10.5.192/static/css/rainloop/v/1.10.5.192/static/css/app.min.css?standard".
```

Some possible (but didnt work) solutions I tried:

1. "include /etc/nginx/mime.types;" is found in nginx.conf.
2. Some say, location for php is screwing up that part, so I should add this line:

   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$; #this line

But still it doesn't work.

3. I add new locations for css and javascript with root but also nothing.

My config is this one: (it is an included file)

```
location ^~ /webmail {
    root /srv/rainloop/public_html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /webmail/index.php?$query_string;
    access_log /srv/rainloop/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/rainloop/logs/error.log;
    index index.php;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/scripts.log scripts;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        #if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
        include fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$; #this line
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/rainloop/public_html/index.php;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ^~ /webmail/data {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think that it can solve your problem.

```
location ~ \.css {
    add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
}
location ~ \.js {
    add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
}
```

Comment: @Sanan_Guliyev I get now a 404 for js and css files. "open() "/var/www/html/rainloop/v/1.10.5.192/static/js/min/boot.min.js" failed" It should be: "/srv/rainloop/public_html/rainloop/v/1.10.5.192/static/js/min/boot.min.js". I have added root inside all these 2 locations but still it doesn't fix the path.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with CSS and Javascript files, that were being served as `text/html`. After trying everything I could think of during hours without any effect, it was automatically solved by restarting Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code block below into the appropriate location block:

```
types {
    text/css css;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines to http {}

```
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain why these should be added?

Comment: @AaronBell
I don't know actually. They're needed for transferring some css files. If you don't add them, some css files don't load and this error come in the inspect page in browser.
As far as i remember, these lines are in default nginx config file (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf). In this file, nginx also includes all config files in conf.d and sites-enables directories. So it's not necessary to add those lines to our nginx file. But if we want to use a custom nginx.conf file, we have to add them.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime with remove

```
<Document html>
```

from top of html file , everything well done.
try it.