# How to load css in nginx using docker file?

Tags: docker, nginx

I am new to writing applications and using nginx I am making a app for my friend's birthday. This is my folder structure

```
 nginx-app
 ┣ Dockerfile
 ┣ pic.jpg
 ┣ style.css
 ┣ index.html
```

Tried to refer :

[docker nginx not loading css styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66887092/docker-nginx-not-loading-css-styles)

But it did not work for me. When I use live server it works as expected but when I try to use docker image to containerise it then it starts to fail. Css does not load can someone help me with this?

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This is how things looks in my live server
[image: expected response]

This is how it looks in my docker image once its deployed

[image: issues when deployed on docker]

Error when I inspect

[image]

Why does this app not load css ? Can someone help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Docker Nginx configuration only looks for files in `/usr/share/nginx/html`.  You're copying `index.html` there, but then copying the rest of the site into a different directory `/app` that Nginx doesn't know about.

The easiest change to make is to `COPY` the entire application into the standard directory

```bash
FROM nginx
COPY ./ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

If you've mixed HTML content and application source, you may want to more explicitly copy specific files or extensions into the directory.

Note that you do not need an `EXPOSE` or `CMD` line for this setup; these are included in the base `nginx` image and your image will inherit these.

Comment: Yes this is what happened copying to app does not make any sense but other point is what i missed should have copied css,jpg etc to `/usr/share/nginx/html`

Answer (score 0):

I had used the below reference

[Deploy html app using nginx](https://thatdevopsguy.medium.com/how-to-create-a-static-web-server-for-html-with-nginx-99bf8226bce6)

From this I could understand that I had to use nginx.conf file.

nginx.conf file that I had used

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    server {
        listen 80;
         
         location = /status {
             access_log off;
             default_type text/plain;
             add_header Content-Type text/plain;
             return 200 "alive";
        }
        
         location / {
            gzip off;
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
            index  index.html;
        }
        
        location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        }
    } 
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
}
```

Dockerfile that I used

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY *.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY *.css /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY *.jpg /usr/share/nginx/html/

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```